# read all the files in a directory in python

Tags: python, file

I am pretty new to python.I have a directory and inside which I have 2 sub directory.Each sub directory contain 100 text file.I want to read the content of each file of the both the sub directory and put them in a single text file in such a way that each file content is in a single line in the new file.how can I achieve this in pyhon.thank you

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Show your attempts and we will help. Please read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, please!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have anything.. you could try starting from here. You can use the glob module instead to load files from a single level of subdirectories, or use os.walk() to walk an arbitrary directory structure depending on your requirement,

To open say all text files in an arbitrary nesting of directories:

```
 import os
 import fnmatch

 for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('Test'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)):
            # deal with this file as next loop will present you with a new file. 
            #use the filename object to do whatever you want with that file
```

Since your new like you said. Watch out for the indentations. #Goodluck